# Android Studio give a FOR loop a delay

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-studio, delay

Im trying to build easy app that the user need to remmber on which buttons the computer pressed .. 
Each button that clicked make a sound .. so in order to make each sound ,sound correctly I tried to give a little bit of delay between each click that the computer pressed...

So I make int[] that include the sequence of the way the computer click the buttons ( for 1 click on button1 , for 2 click on button 2 .... ) 
and now im trying to acually pressed the button haha
so I made this :

```
   private void ClickButtons(int[] sequence) {
        Button btcomp1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btComp1);
        Button btcomp2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btComp2);
        Button btcomp3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btComp3);
        Button btcomp4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btComp4);
        TextView check=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewKq);
        Handler handler = new Handler();

        for (int i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++)
        {
            switch (sequence[i]) {
                case 1:
                    btcomp1.performClick();
                    check.setText("4..");
                    timedelay();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    btcomp2.performClick();
                    check.setText("3..");
                    timedelay();

                    break;
                case 3:
                    btcomp3.performClick();
                    check.setText("2..");
                    timedelay();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    btcomp4.performClick();
                    check.setText("1..");
                    timedelay();
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
```

it didnt work well , I even thought that their is may be problem with the button so I set it for changing some Textview but its seems that its only enter to one case ... and the only delay was when I mover from the FirstActivity to the GameActivity

I really have nothing in the FirstActivity just field for UserName ...

Well I hopes you helped me guys and soory for grammer ><

This is the delay .. I tried to do something but all that do is to delay me a few seconds after I gor from actity 1 to another but do nothing in the main ..

```
 private void timedelay() {
    try{
        Thread.sleep(2500);
    }
    catch (Exception e){

    }
}
```

Comment: who is timedelay() sir? show him, also do not delay on the thread your views live in - hope yo get me?

Comment: Actually, what is your `timedelay` method doing? Show us the code

Comment: "it didnt work well" -- do tell!

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of thing you should definitely use the `android.os.Handler` to make a timer. And in the callback method, click the buttons. The method you are using now will probably block the main thread. This is really bad.

Luckily, I have already written a `Timer` class does this! Here is the whole class:

```
import android.os.Handler;

public class Timer {
    private Handler handler;
    private boolean paused;

    private int interval;

    private Runnable task = new Runnable () {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!paused) {
                runnable.run ();
                Timer.this.handler.postDelayed (this, interval);
            }
        }
    };

    private Runnable runnable;

    public int getInterval() {
        return interval;
    }

    public void setInterval(int interval) {
        this.interval = interval;
    }

    public void startTimer () {
        paused = false;
        handler.postDelayed (task, interval);
    }

    public void stopTimer () {
        paused = true;
    }

    public Timer (Runnable runnable, int interval, boolean started) {
        handler = new Handler ();
        this.runnable = runnable;
        this.interval = interval;
        if (started)
            startTimer ();
    }
}
```

Try to understand it. After you do that, you can use this timer like this:

```
final Timer t = new Timer(new Runnable() {
    private int i = 1;
    Button btcomp1 = (Button) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.btComp1);
    Button btcomp2 = (Button) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.btComp2);
    Button btcomp3 = (Button) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.btComp3);
    Button btcomp4 = (Button) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.btComp4);
    TextView check=(TextView)MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.textViewKq);
    public void run() {
        switch (i) {
            case 1:
                btcomp1.performClick();
                check.setText("4..");
                break;
            case 2:
                btcomp2.performClick();
                check.setText("3..");
                break;
            case 3:
                btcomp3.performClick();
                check.setText("2..");
                break;
            case 4:
                btcomp4.performClick();
                check.setText("1..");
                t.stopTimer();
                break;
        }
    }
}, 1000, true);
```

Once this timer is created, it basically presses a button once a second. And set the text of `check`. When it presses it the fourth time, the timer stops.

Easy! (if you have the timer class)